# Is displaying the animation for Photo Roll GIFs possible?

Tags: ios

I want to create an iOS app that takes a GIF from the photo roll and displays its animation.
Is there some kind of technical limitation preventing this? I found [this](http://iosnotestoremember.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/showing-animated-gif-in-ios.html), which suggests it's not a perfectly straightforward thing but possible with a bit of hacking...

Background: I want the app's functionality for myself; I haven't found anything on the store that does so.  It doesn't *seem* like it would be a difficult app. But the fact that it doesn't exist makes me nervous that it isn't actually doable.

Comment: No "hacking" is required.  You just need to understand and be able to parse the GIF file format.  It may or may not be hard but it is certainly not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Add these class in your project**

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIImage (animatedGIF)
+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:(NSData *)theData;
+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)theURL;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define toCF (__bridge CFTypeRef)
#define fromCF (__bridge id)
#else
#define toCF (CFTypeRef)
#define fromCF (id)
#endif

@implementation UIImage (animatedGIF)

static int delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex(CGImageSourceRef const source, size_t const i) {
    int delayCentiseconds = 1;
    CFDictionaryRef const properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    if (properties) {
        CFDictionaryRef const gifProperties = CFDictionaryGetValue(properties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary);
        CFRelease(properties);
        if (gifProperties) {
            CFNumberRef const number = CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime);

            delayCentiseconds = (int)lrint([fromCF number doubleValue] * 100);
        }
    }
    return delayCentiseconds;
}

static void createImagesAndDelays(CGImageSourceRef source, size_t count, CGImageRef imagesOut[count], int delayCentisecondsOut[count]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        imagesOut[i] = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
        delayCentisecondsOut[i] = delayCentisecondsForImageAtIndex(source, i);
    }
}

static int sum(size_t const count, int const *const values) {
    int theSum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        theSum += values[i];
    }
    return theSum;
}

static int pairGCD(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b)
        return pairGCD(b, a);
    while (true) {
        int const r = a % b;
        if (r == 0)
            return b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
}

static int vectorGCD(size_t const count, int const *const values) {
    int gcd = values[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {

        gcd = pairGCD(values[i], gcd);
    }
    return gcd;
}

static NSArray *frameArray(size_t const count, CGImageRef const images[count], int const delayCentiseconds[count], int const totalDurationCentiseconds) {
    int const gcd = vectorGCD(count, delayCentiseconds);
    size_t const frameCount = totalDurationCentiseconds / gcd;
    UIImage *frames[frameCount];
    for (size_t i = 0, f = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        UIImage *const frame = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:images[i]];
        for (size_t j = delayCentiseconds[i] / gcd; j > 0; --j) {
            frames[f++] = frame;
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frames count:frameCount];
}

static void releaseImages(size_t const count, CGImageRef const images[count]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        CGImageRelease(images[i]);
    }
}

static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(CGImageSourceRef const source) {
    size_t const count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);
    CGImageRef images[count];
    int delayCentiseconds[count]; // in centiseconds
    createImagesAndDelays(source, count, images, delayCentiseconds);
    int const totalDurationCentiseconds = sum(count, delayCentiseconds);
    NSArray *const frames = frameArray(count, images, delayCentiseconds, totalDurationCentiseconds);
    UIImage *const animation = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:frames duration:(NSTimeInterval)totalDurationCentiseconds / 100.0];
    releaseImages(count, images);
    return animation;
}

static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceRef source) {
    if (source) {
        UIImage *const image = animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(source);
        CFRelease(source);
        return image;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:(NSData *)data {
    return animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceCreateWithData(toCF data, NULL));
}

+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFReleasingImageSource(CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(toCF url, NULL));
}

@end
```

Wrote the below code for retrieve the gif image path and set in the UIImageView.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:<imageFileName> withExtension:@"gif"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: That code is from my [`uiimage-from-animated-gif` repository](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif), but you haven't explained how to combine it with the Assets Library.